# How can I achieve a back-and-forth synchronized inter-process communication between two processes without sleep()

Tags: c, process, synchronization, mutex, producer-consumer

So the problem is this:

> There are two processes, a foreground and a background process. Both
> share an integer array. The foreground process accepts integers
> through the terminal and appends each integer to the shared array. The
> background process keeps the shared array sorted in ascending order
> after each addition. When the last element is placed in its correct
> position the foreground process then displays the shared array on the
> terminal.

This is my implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 64
#define BUFFER_NAME "/shared"

struct data {
  int buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
  sem_t mutex;
};


int foreground_process(int size)
{
  int element;

  int buff_fd = shm_open(BUFFER_NAME, O_RDWR, 0666);
  struct data *D = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct data), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, buff_fd, 0);

  sem_init(&(D->mutex), 7, 1); 

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    sem_wait(&(D->mutex));
      printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
      scanf("%d", &element);
      
      D->buffer[i] = element;
    sem_post(&(D->mutex));

    sleep(1);
  }

  sem_wait(&(D->mutex));
    printf("Final array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      printf("%d ", D->buffer[i]);
    printf("\n");
  sem_post(&(D->mutex));

  close(buff_fd);

  exit(0);
}

int background_process(int size)
{
  int prev_element, tmp;

  int buff_fd = shm_open(BUFFER_NAME, O_RDWR, 0666);
  struct data *D = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct data), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, buff_fd, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    sem_wait(&(D->mutex));
    
    prev_element = D->buffer[i];
    printf("Got element %d at B[%d]!\n", D->buffer[i], i);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
      if (D->buffer[j] > prev_element) {
        tmp = D->buffer[j];
        D->buffer[j] = prev_element;
        prev_element = tmp;
      }
    }

    D->buffer[i] = prev_element;

    sem_post(&(D->mutex));

    sleep(1);
  }

  close(buff_fd);

  exit(0);
}

int main(void) {
  int size;
  pid_t fg_pid, bg_pid;

  pid_t wpid;
  int status;

  printf("Size: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  int buff_fd = shm_open(BUFFER_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
  ftruncate(buff_fd, sizeof(struct data));

  if ((fg_pid = fork()) == 0) foreground_process(size);
  else if (fg_pid < 0) perror("foreground process");

  sleep(1);

  if ((bg_pid = fork()) == 0) background_process(size);
  else if (bg_pid < 0) perror("background process");

  while ((wpid = wait(&status)) != - 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "Process %d exists with status %d\n", wpid, WEXITSTATUS(status));

  shm_unlink(BUFFER_NAME);

  return 0;
}
```

The data object to be shared is a `struct` containing an integer array & a binary semaphore (for synchronization)

This works:
Sample O/P:

```
Size: 5
Enter element 0: 2
Got element 2 at B[0]!
Enter element 1: 10
Got element 10 at B[1]!
Enter element 2: 1
Got element 1 at B[2]!
Enter element 3: 9
Got element 9 at B[3]!
Enter element 4: 8
Got element 8 at B[4]!
Final array: 1 2 8 9 10 
Process 1849 exists with status 0
Process 1850 exists with status 0
```

But this isn't a legitimate solution since I'm using `sleep()` 3 times to achieve this back-and-forth synchronization. Once between forking the background & the foreground process, to make sure that the foreground process runs first. Second & third, after each iteration of the `for` loops in the foreground & background processes.

Removing the `sleep()` creates all sorts of problem, the background process for instance seems to get starved off the `mutex` & hence doesn't seem to run etc., the background process sometimes runs before the foreground process.

So any modifications I can make to sort this mess out?

Comment: `sem_t mutex;`?  Please don't use the name `mutex` for a semaphore.  A semaphore is not a mutex - they are different things and work in completely different manners.  Anyone who fails to recognize that is promoting code that is needlessly less readable and understandable than it would otherwise be.

Answer (score 3):

`sleep()` has no legitimate role to play in thread- or process-synchronization schemes.  Instead, use proper IPC mechanisms such as mutexes, semaphores, condition variables, and pipes.

Your attempt to do that without `sleep` does not work reliably for a couple of reasons:

- You have a race condition for setting up the semaphore.  You rely on the foreground process to do this, but without the artificial delay, the background process may try to wait on the semaphore before it is ready.

  There is more than one way to approach the problem, but I would suggest just having the parent initialize the semaphore, as it does the shared memory, so that it is already ready when each of the other programs starts.
- The foreground and background processes wait on the same semaphore for clearance to proceed.  If you mean for them to take turns then this is logically flawed: the two both interpret and consume the same "go" signal.  The `sleep` does not solve this, but it does reduce the (otherwise high) likelihood that one process will increment the semaphore, loop around, and then decrement it again without giving the other process a chance to run.

  If you want to do this with semaphores then use *two*.  Each process waits on a different one of them for clearance to proceed, and posts to the other to let the other process go.

Answer (score 0):

To compliment [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724276/2505965), here is modified version of your example using two semaphores to create a *lockstep* between the two processes.

Note how the semaphores are initialized in the parent process, and the exact ordering of each `sem_wait` and `sem_post`.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 64
#define BUFFER_NAME "/shared"

struct data {
    int buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    sem_t input;
    sem_t sorting;
};

static int cmp(const void *ap, const void *bp)
{
    int a = *(const int *)ap;
    int b = *(const int *)bp;

    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

static struct data *get_shared_data(int creat)
{
    int fd = shm_open(BUFFER_NAME, creat | O_RDWR, 0666);

    if (creat)
        ftruncate(fd, sizeof (struct data));

    struct data *dat = mmap(NULL, sizeof *dat,
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    close(fd);
    return dat;
}

static void foreground_process(int size)
{
    struct data *dat = get_shared_data(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sem_wait(&dat->input);

        printf("Enter #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (1 != scanf("%d", dat->buffer + i))
            dat->buffer[i] = i;

        sem_post(&dat->sorting);
    }

    sem_wait(&dat->input);

    printf("Result: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", dat->buffer[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    exit(0);
}

static void background_process(int size)
{
    struct data *dat = get_shared_data(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sem_wait(&dat->sorting);

        printf("Got B[%d] as %d\n", i, dat->buffer[i]);
        qsort(dat->buffer, i + 1, sizeof *dat->buffer, cmp);

        sem_post(&dat->input);
    }

    exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int size;
    pid_t fg_pid, bg_pid;

    pid_t wpid;
    int status;

    printf("Size: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &size) || !size || size > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid size.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct data *dat = get_shared_data(O_CREAT);
    sem_init(&dat->input, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&dat->sorting, 1, 0);

    if ((fg_pid = fork()) == 0) foreground_process(size);
    else if (fg_pid < 0) perror("foreground process");

    if ((bg_pid = fork()) == 0) background_process(size);
    else if (bg_pid < 0) perror("background process");

    while ((wpid = wait(&status)) != - 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Process %d exists with status %d\n", wpid, WEXITSTATUS(status));

    sem_destroy(&dat->input);
    sem_destroy(&dat->sorting);
    shm_unlink(BUFFER_NAME);
}
```

Result using the same inputs:

```
Size: 5
Enter #1: 2
Got B[0] as 2
Enter #2: 10
Got B[1] as 10
Enter #3: 1
Got B[2] as 1
Enter #4: 9
Got B[3] as 9
Enter #5: 8
Got B[4] as 8
Result: 1 2 8 9 10 
Process 148440 exists with status 0
Process 148439 exists with status 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of synchronized back and forth producer-consumer tasks using the Ada programming language.

Ada provides a mechanism for synchronous task communication using the Rendezvous model. Ada tasks communicate directly using one or more task entries. A task entry may pass data from the calling task to the called task or from the called task to the calling task. Task entries can also be implemented without passing any data at all. In that case a task call acts as a simple event notification.

Task entry synchronization is implicitly handled by the language. There is no explicit call to any semaphore or mutex. When a task calls the entry to another task the calling task is suspended until the called task accepts the entry. Similarly, if a called task encounters an accept statement for a task entry it is suspended until another task calls the entry. When both tasks (calling and called) are simultaneously calling and accepting the same entry any specified data is transferred from one task to the other. Upon completion of the data transfer the tasks resume their concurrent behaviors.

Synchronous task communication has been a feature of the core Ada language since the 1983 version of the Ada standard.

The following solution to the problem specified in this question uses two tasks communicating through two task entries.

```ada
-- There are two processes, a foreground and a background process.
-- Both share an integer array. The foreground process accepts integers
-- through the terminal and appends each integer to the shared array.
-- The background process keeps the shared array sorted in ascending order
-- after each addition. When the last element is placed in its correct
-- position the foreground process then displays the shared array on
-- the terminal.

-- The main procedure executes in the foreground process.
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort;

procedure Main is
   type Nums_array is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;

   procedure print (A : Nums_array) is
   begin
      for V of A loop
         Put (V'Image & " ");
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end print;

   Num_Elements : Positive;

begin
   Put ("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
   Get (Num_Elements);
   declare
      subtype arr is Nums_array (1 .. Num_Elements);

      task background is
         entry add_element (Item : in Integer);
         entry get_result (Item : out arr);
      end background;

      task body background is
         procedure sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort
           (Index_Type => Positive, Element_Type => Integer,
            Array_Type => Nums_array);
         Result : arr := (others => Integer'First);
      begin
         for I in Result'Range loop
            accept add_element (Item : in Integer) do
               Result (Result'First) := Item;
            end add_element;
            sort (Result);
         end loop;

         accept get_result (Item : out arr) do
            Item := Result;
         end get_result;
      end background;
      Input  : Integer;
      Output : arr;
   begin
      Put_Line ("Enter the array values:");
      for I in arr'Range loop
         Get (Input);
         background.add_element (Input);
      end loop;
      background.get_result (Output);
      print (Output);
      New_Line;
   end;

end Main;
```

The Nums_array type is an unconstrained array type, meaning any particular instance of the type may be a different length within the limits imposed by the index type. In this example the index type is Positive. Positive is a pre-defined subtype of Integer with a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of Integer'Last, which is usually the same as MAX_INT in C.

The Main procedure (which is also the Main task or thread) declares a local variable  named Num_Elements which is an instance of the subtype Positive.

The user is prompted for the number of elements in the array and the response is assigned to Num_Elements.

An inner block is started at the "declare" reserved word. Ada requires all types, variables, and constants to be declared in the declarative region of a block, function, procedure, task or package. In this example a subtype of Nums_array is defined to be an array type with the index range beginning at 1 and ending at Num_Elements.

A background task is defined with two entries.

- The add_element entry allows the foreground task to send a value to
  the background task. The value is passed IN to the background task.
- The get_result entry allows the background task to pass the sorted
  array to the foreground task. The value is passed OUT of the background task.
  The implementation of the background task is defined within the task body.
  The task body declarative region is used to instantiate the generic sort procedure found in the package Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort. After that an instance of the subtype arr, named Result, is created and all values in the array are initialized to Integer'First, which is generally the same as MIN_INT in C.

The background task iterates through the Result array, accepting a value from the add_element entry in each iteration. After accepting the new value from the foreground task the array is sorted.
When all the elements have been added to the array the background array accepts the get_result entry and passes the entire array to the foreground task. The background task then terminates.

The main procedure is also the foreground task. It therefore prompts the user to enter values for all the Num_Elements array elements, calling background.add_element each time and passing the entered value to the background task. Upon completing the input loop the main task calls background.get_result and prints the values of the array passed to it by the background task.

The communication between the foreground task and the background task is fully synchronized without explicit manipulation of synchronization primitives.

---

A second version written using Ada implements a shared buffer accessed by the foreground task and the background task. The shared buffer is implemented using an Ada protected object. Ada protected objects are automatically protected from inappropriate task access.

Protected objects can be accessed through three kinds of protected methods. Those methods are:

- functions, which implement a shared read-only lock on the data
  encapsulated within the protected object. The shared read-only lock
  allows multiple tasks to read data from the protected object
  simultaneously, since read-only access prevents any race conditions.
- procedures, which implement an unconditional exclusive read-write
  lock on the data encapsulated within the protected object. Only one
  task at a time is allowed to hold the read-write lock.
- entries, which implement a conditional read-write exclusive lock on
  the data encapsulated within the protected object. Each entry has an
  associated boundary condition which must evaluate to TRUE to gain
  access to the protected object. While the boundary condition
  evaluates to FALSE the calling tasks are suspended and placed in an
  implicitly implemented entry FIFO queue, waiting for the boundary
  condition to evaluate to TRUE.
  The following example only uses protected entries to control access to the array in the protected object, thus ensuring that the foreground task can only write to the buffer when the buffer has no new elements and the background task can only sort the array when the buffer has a new element. The foreground task can get a copy of the shared array only when the array is in a fully sorted condition.

Ada protected objects were added to the language as part of the Ada 1995 standard.

The Ada program code for this solution is:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort;

procedure buffered_back_forth is
   type Nums_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Integer with
      Default_Component_Value => Integer'First;
   Num_Elements : Positive;
begin
   Put ("Enter the number of array elements: ");
   Get (Num_Elements);

   declare
      subtype arr is Nums_Array (1 .. Num_Elements);

      protected buffer is
         entry add_element (Item : in Integer);
         entry sort_array;
         entry get_buffer (Item : out Nums_Array);
      private
         Buf         : arr;
         New_Element : Boolean := False;
      end buffer;

      protected body buffer is
         entry add_element (Item : in Integer) when not New_Element is
         begin
            Buf (Buf'First) := Item;
            New_Element     := True;
         end add_element;

         entry sort_array when New_Element is
            procedure sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Array_Sort
              (Index_Type => Positive, Element_Type => Integer,
               Array_Type => Nums_Array);
         begin
            sort (Buf);
            New_Element := False;
         end sort_array;

         entry get_buffer (Item : out Nums_Array) when not New_Element is
         begin
            Item := Buf;
         end get_buffer;
      end buffer;

      task background;

      task body background is
      begin
         for I in arr'Range loop
            buffer.sort_array;
         end loop;
      end background;

      New_Num : Integer;
      Result  : arr;
   begin
      Put_Line ("Enter the array values:");
      for I in arr'Range loop
         Get (New_Num);
         buffer.add_element (New_Num);
      end loop;
      buffer.get_buffer (Result);
      for value of Result loop
         Put (value'Image & " ");
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end;
end buffered_back_forth;
```